# There is a problem when opening Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, elinks

I installed Anaconda 3 in Linux and tried to open Jupyter notebook in browser by typing 'jupyter notebook' in terminal.

But what I've got is the screen I added below.

As I guess, Jupyter Notebook is currently opened via 'Elinks', but I have no idea about what this is.

Do you know how to open Jupyter Notebook in the browser I want, such as Firefox or Chrome?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add some information in case you wanted to later access juypter notebook via elinks (or any other text-based web browser in terminal).
I will also go over opening jupyter notebook with Anaconda Navigator.

First, You need to first install Node.js Javascript Runtime Environment by running this command in terminal.
`sudo apt-get install node.js`

Next, close and reopen terminal (I always do this when installing new software via command line).

When you next try to access your jupyter notebook via elinks it will ask for a token or password.

Option 1 : Token.
Find the token by entering `jupyter notebook list` in terminal.

Option 2 : Password.
You can create a password for jupyter notebook by entering `jupyter notebook password` in the terminal.

You can now use the token or your newly created password in order to access jupyter notebook via full-featured text web browser such as elinks.

If you want to access jupyter notebook via Firefox, Chrome, etc. then just use anaconda. This will automatically open jupyter notebook in your standard web browser.
Enter `anaconda-navigator` in terminal.
Once anaconda navigator opens, simply launch jupyter notebook from the selection.

Comment: What does installing Java have to do with running Jupyter Notebook? Also, the commands you mentioned don't even install Java. Are you confusing Java with JavaScript?

Comment: @SumnerEvans Hi. I had announced in the post that I am a beginner in GNU/Linux command line & Python and to bare with me. This has disappeared for some reason. I may have confused JavaScript with Java. But I can tell you that once I downloaded Java I got past the screen that Young Oh Son had screenshotted, which is part of the process of enabling Jupiter notebook on elinks.

Comment: Installing Java to fix this problem is way out of proportion to what needs to be done. It's not even a hack because it doesn't do that! If you don't know what you're talking about, you shouldn't be answering questions.

Comment: Thanks for input! I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set Firefox or Chrome as [default browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79305/how-do-i-change-my-default-browser), then it should open directly in it.

If it still doesn't, you can always copy the URLs which are displayed when jupyter notebook is started, and paste it in your browser.

```
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/harshit/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2985-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=9fc770713dbd755750bbe842896420ecfa7abc038581fc04
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=9fc770713dbd755750bbe842896420ecfa7abc038581fc04
```

By the way, jupyter notebook doesn't work, because, by default, JS is not enabled in eLinks browser (you can [enable](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=228455) it).